# Load Balance with proxmox and kubernetes with 3 physical server

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes, high-availability, proxmox

We have 3 physical servers and We want to build a HA Kubernetes cluster on it. At the moment We use proxmox ve 6.2 and VM-s for Kubernetes.

How can I provide load balancing between the three servers?

If I create a Proxmox Cluster with the servers can I do it somehow internally? The goal is a HA system with load balancing without an external load-balancing solution.

If load balancing not possible with Proxmox Cluster is there any reason to create it? Kubernetes can do a HA system itself.

Comment: It really depends on what you need to load balance. Do you need a load balancer for an HA Kubernetes API server (to make the master itself HA)? Or do you need a load balancer for distributed pods? There's a difference - One is not expected to be handled by Kubernetes' connection to a cloud API to create load balancer objects (in the case of establishing an HA Kubernetes master), and the other is generally accomplished by providing a sufficient API for kubernetes to create load balancer objects upstream of service objects.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn’t sound as though you’ve fully understood the components you’re talking about. Proxmox is a virtualization platform which if correctly configured can aid in providing good uptime and restart VMs or containers on another host if one host dies for you. Load balancing happens higher up in the stack.

If you read the Kubernetes documentation, it states that you need an ingress controller for load balancing, with a number of examples given; generally well-known reverse proxies/load balancers.

Comment: Ah, not exactly (regarding ingress). You don't need an ingress controller for load balancing. An ingress controller is typically something like a reverse proxy that allows a single load balancer object to serve one or more service objects, or that otherwise provides an in-stack data route to services. This eliminates the need to handle ingress for each exposed service, and makes routing via DNS name easy.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!